# Scene Builder, how to add multiple tasks on button click

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have this code

```
playButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            primaryStage.show();
            startGame();
            menuStage.close();
        });
```

Now I want to delete this code and operate in Scene builder. How do I insert all three tasks that I have there to Scenebuilder Code -> On Action. Do I have to separate them somehow with semicolon? Right now I can only write one task in the field.

Comment: Use a controller. ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/custom_control.htm ) You do not have access to those variables/methods, even if you enable javascript in the fxml...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item you are specifying in the "On Action" box in SceneBuilder is actually the name of a method in the controller, not a statement to execute. So simply define a method in the controller class with the required code:

```
@FXML
private void startGame() {
    primaryStage.show();
    startGame();
    menuStage.close();
}
```

and then reference it in Scene Builder:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That helped me!